# How to use isinstance to test all possible integer types

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, types, isinstance

When working with integers there are multiple types available (e.g. int, numpy.int8, numpy.int16, etc.).  If I write a generic function that requires one variable to be an integer how can I test the type against all possible "integer" types within Python/numpy?  The same can be asked about floats.  I initially thought this

```
isinstance(np.int64(5), int)
```

would/should work, but it doesn't.

Is there a way I can test an integer variable for *all* available integer types?

Comment: Not really. You can only create a tuple of the int types manually and use it as second argument for "isinstance".

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's what I thought.  I was just hoping for something a little more elegant.  But, if it works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) and [`numbers.Real`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) respectively:

```
from numbers import Integral, Real

isinstance(x, Integral)
isinstance(x, Real)
```

Comment: Real doesn't provide the same kind of test as Integral does, it just tests whether x is real or not.  While isinstance(np.int64(x), Integral) returns True, so does isinstance(np.int64, Real)...so it's not testing for a float type.

Comment: @tnknepp `isinstance` doesn't check for type identity, it checks whether the given object is compatible with the given type(s). This includes abstract base classes which form the numeric tower as defined in the `numbers` module. That's also how static type checkers handle the situation (i.e. `x: float = 1` passes). If that's not what you want, then you need to provide the exact list of (concrete) types to check. But if you already know that `isinstance(x, Integral)` why would you check `isinstance(x, Real)`?

Comment: I was confused about why you included the Real example.  I tangentially mentioned floats in the original post so I thought you were suggesting Real could be used to test for a float, which made no sense at all.  I get it now.  Is there a similar test for floats?

Comment: @tnknepp Perhaps I'm not fully understanding what you mean. `Real` tests for *compatibility* with float, i.e. if `isinstance(x, Real)` then `float(x)` will succeed. If you only need to distinguish between two data types, int and float, then testing for `Integral` is sufficient. If you want to distinguish complex numbers as well, then you'd need an additional test for `Real`. What do you want to test in the end?

Comment: This is getting off topic from the original question (my fault).  I was just wondering if there is a way to determine if something is a float and nothing else.  Real will return true for a float and integer, so it's not exclusive.  That said, I think I have all the information I need.

Answer (score 5):

In *Python* there is only a single `int` type. If you want to test all integer types in `numpy`, plus the built-in `int` type, you can use:

```
isinstance(x, (int, np.integer))
```

Where `np.integer` is an abstract base class of all scalar numpy integer types. Similarly for float,

```
isinstance(x, (float, np.floating))
```