# Best way to check if a variable is a number (int, float, np.float32, np.int64, ...) in python?

Tags: python, numpy, isinstance

I am running in this multiple times now and never found a satisfying solution.

I want to check: **Is variable `some_var` of a number type?**
More specific for me: Can it be compared to another number? (e.g. a string should fail)

Numpy makes this somehow difficult since:

```py
some_var = np.int32(123)
isinstance(some_var, int)
>>> False
```

## Possible Solutions

### numpy solutions: `np.issubtype`, comparison to `np.number`, `np.isscalar`

I found `np.issubtype` as workaround, but this will fail for non-numpy types:

```py
some_var = 123
np.issubdtype(some_var.dtype, np.number)
>>> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

`np.number` can be used for comparison, but also fails for non-numpy types

```py
isinstance(1, np.number)
>>> False
```

`np.isscalar()` works fine, but also allows strings:

```py
np.isscalar('test')
>>>True
```

### `numbers` module

[There is the comparison with the `numbers` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283951/how-to-use-isinstance-to-test-all-possible-integer-types). Which seems to work convenient, but needs an extra import. So far probably the best solution.

```py
from numbers import Integral

isinstance(some_var, Integral)
>>> True
```

### Manual testing

The clearest way of course would be a manual test.

```py
isinstance(some_var, (int, float, np.int32, np.int64, np.float32, np.float64))
>>> True
```

## My Questions

Am I missing a way?
What would be the most recommended?

Comment: You can use `np.issubdtype(some_var, np.number)`..

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138202/using-isdigit-for-floats, I think the first answer is what you need

Comment: Does `'12.3'` count as number or string?

Comment: `isinstance(some_var, np.number)` works too.  As long at is dtype a number and not a string that contains the representation of a number as hpaulj implies.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated the question that in my case `'12.3'` (strings) should not count and added the `isinstance(...,np.number)` solution, which sadly won't work for int and float.

Answer (score 1):

As the short answer did not catch the audience, here the extended answer:
There is no generic function to check against every numeric type in existance, as every package can implement their own.

It is also advisable, to control, which variable types to accept, as packages can have different implementation behaviour (e.g. integer division `1 / 10 = 0.1 or 1 / 10 = 0`.

Therefore a simple `isNumeric` check is advisable.

Now two versions come to my mind:

```
NUMERIC_TYPES = [int, float, ...] #to be extended by acceptable types
def isNumeric(val):
    return isinstance(val, NUMERIC_TYPES)
```

however there is a more performant version (my laptop 15%)

```
NUMERIC_TYPES = set((int, float, np.int32, np.int64, np.float32, np.float64,...))

def isNumeric(val):
    return type(val) in NUMERIC_TYPES
```

And for @CodePrinz `isinstance` and `type(x)==` is not the same!

```
class StupidInt(int):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._privateInt = val
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._privateInt - other

a = StupidInt(10)
b = StupidInt(10)
print("a + b = 0? whaaat?")
print(a+b)

print("isInstance: {}".format(isinstance(a, int)))
print("is of type: {}".format(type(a) == int))
----
a + b = 0? whaaat?
0
isInstance: True
is of type: False
```

Comment: This will not work for numpy types as np.int32.

Comment: and `isinstance(val, (int, float))` does the same and is more obvious.

Comment: well obviously, the numericTypes is supposed to be extended to the full set of accepted data types. And also it is nicer to abstract it to a function, that does express the purpose (and is shorter than repeating ```ìsinstance(....)```. And third, isInstance at least in the past does have a reputation for being slow. A lookup against a set is ```O(1)``` quiet efficient

Comment: @CodePrinz please look at the update. there are definitly reasons not to use isinstance.

Comment: Thanks for the more elaborated answer! In my case I think every child of an allowed class would be good to go.
I was taught to prefer of-the-shelf solutions to selft-written functions. Of course often such a replacement can make sense.