# Replace values of rows on specific condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

df1

```
Name English Maths City
Hdhdn  65    50   Xyz
Hdhdhd 70.6    45   Abc
John   67.4    46   Ydh
```

I want to replace all numeric values for John to 0

Result would look like this

```
Name English Maths City
Hdhdn  65    50   Xyz
Hdhdhd 70.6    45   Abc
John    0    0   Ydh
```

I would like to know what would be the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you potentially have mixed dtypes, a robust (but non-vectorized) method could be to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) on the "John" rows, then to [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame in place:

```
df.update(df.loc[df['Name'].eq('John')]
            .applymap(lambda x: 0 if isinstance(x, (float, int)) else x)
          )

print(df)
```

*NB. assuming the original numbers are `int`/`float`, you could [add more types to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978494/16343464) in `isinstance` if needed.*

Output:

```
     Name  English  Maths City
0   Hdhdn     65.0     50  Xyz
1  Hdhdhd     70.6     45  Abc
2    John      0.0      0  Ydh
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.loc[df['Name'].eq('John'), df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns] = 0
print (df)
     Name  English  Maths City
0   Hdhdn     65.0     50  Xyz
1  Hdhdhd     70.6     45  Abc
2    John      0.0      0  Ydh
```